# Codeigniter - global XSS filtering TRUE

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss, non-ascii-characters

i setted up this in my config.php:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

the problem for me is that it removes all the accented chars like "à,ù,è,ò"

is this usual?

also why replacing them? how can i leave them?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to leave the accented characters you can use the `convert_accented_characters()` function of `text_helper` which will transliterate high ASCII characters to low ASCII equivalents. You have to load the helper first.
Documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html)

Comment: nope, the problem is that before i can use the convert_accented_characters() method the string is replaced yet by the config global xsss filter :P